# Regex: How to capture a group that is followed by '+' (greedy plus)?

Tags: regex

Just say I have the following text to be processed by regex:

```
  red red red blue
```

To match the text, I use the following regex:

```
  (red\s*)+(blue)
```

Now, my question is that how to capture the first **groups** (not the first **group**) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add parenthesis around what you want to capture, in this case the whole `+`ed group:

```
((red\s*)+)(blue)
```